# How do I turn off fullscreen in Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, fullscreen, kivy, python-3.4

All Kivy (1.8.0) applications run fullscreen on my PC by default. I need to turn fullscreen off for only one (not for each) Kivy application. Strange, but I haven't found the answer for this simple question. Probably, that's not Kivy, but Pygame, but anyway I don't know how to trun it off. Kivy and Pygame were taken from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: I didn't use Kivy - but see [Pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen)

Comment: @furas, I've tried, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure the way window will be displayed using `kivy.config.Config` before importing any Kivy module. For example, to have fullscreen application (this shouldn't be enabled by default):

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
```

In your case you can try to set it explicitly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')

from kivy.app import App

class TestApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

You can find details about `graphics:fullscreen` option in [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html).

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question but if anyone runs in to this problem again and you want to set the config options as default.

In a terminal.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
Config.write()
```

Comment: This should be the preferred answer! I've been running some examples and one "remembered" being fullscreen - then they all proceeded to run that way. Using this answer as a quick config reset tool, *with* `Config.write()`, the problem is permanently resolved (at least until something else changes that saved config). Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the Raspberry Pi 3 only supports full screen mode, so this setting will be ignored. [Kivy won't listen to “fulllscreen” setting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57564/kivy-wont-listen-to-fulllscreen-setting)