# Prevent KIVY starting fullscreen

Tags: kivy

When I run the Kivy code, the window becomes full screen and how it can get smaller.?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764191/how-do-i-turn-off-fullscreen-in-kivy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `fullscreen=1` in your config.ini file
please read https://kivy.org/docs/guide/config.html on where to find config.ini in your platform.

also you can put this in your code ...

```
Window.fullscreen = 0
```